# populate dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having an issue where I have 3 select inputs date(day month year). I would like to populate them using the corresponding hidden input field value. Does anyone have a good idea on how to do it using jquery?

By the way, everything is in the same file and the value from the hidden field should populate their parents selected boxes respectively

```
<select class="day dateselect">
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
<select class="month dateselect">
  <option data-date='1'>January</option>
  <option data-date='2'>February</option>
  <option data-date='3'>March</option>
</select>
<select class="year">
  <option>2010</option>
  <option>2011</option>
  <option>2012</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="startDate" value="2010/1/18"/>

<select class="day dateselect">
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
</select>
<select class="month dateselect">
  <option data-date='1'>January</option>
  <option data-date='2'>February</option>
  <option data-date='3'>March</option>
</select>
<select class="year">
  <option>2010</option>
  <option>2011</option>
  <option>2012</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="endDate" value="2011/3/19"/>

<select class="day dateselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="month dateselect">
  <option data-date='1'>January</option>
  <option data-date='2'>February</option>
  <option data-date='3'>March</option>
</select>
<select class="year">
  <option>2010</option>
  <option>2011</option>
  <option>2012</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="birthDate" value="2010/1/1"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you're not trying to add the selected value to the hidden inputs, but the other way around? Would these new values just be appended to what's already there, or actually populate, as in replace the content of the select with one single value?

Comment: it is the other way around. 
this value should not be appended.
what i meant is that for example, for the case of <input type="hidden" id="endDate" value="2011/3/19"/> we should be able to have 
<select class="day dateselect">
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option selected>19</option>
</select>
<select class="month dateselect">
  <option data-date='1'>January</option>
  <option data-date='2'>February</option>
  <option data-date='3' selected>March</option>
</select>
<select class="year">
  <option>2010</option>
  <option>2011</option selected>
  <option>2012</option>
</select>

Comment: so you can see selected being added to the dropdown accordingly

Comment: I posted an answer, getting actual names of months, days before, even past year, month etc. is a lot harder, and you would need a map of months, date objects and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value of each hidden input, split it and set the value of the previous elements:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(_,el) {
    var date = el.value.split('/');
    $(this).prevAll('.day').first().val(date.pop());
    $(this).prevAll('.month').first().find('option[data-date="'+date.pop()+'"]').prop('selected',true);
    $(this).prevAll('.year').first().val(date.pop());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NAZ2F/1/)

Comment: i just wanted to be selected

Comment: the solution u gave is creating a new option set which it's not what it should. it should be able to change it to selected according to day month and year that we have in our hidden field value

Comment: @user2557307 - I guess I was thrown off by the fact that the dates don't match, but did you check the fiddle in the comment above ?

Comment: I just did and it is working perfectly. :) 
by the way i saw u doing ".each(function(_,el)", what does "_" means in this case? what does it refer to?

Comment: $.each is just a loop, iterating over all the hidden elements?

Comment: what about the dash and el as arguments?

Comment: The first argument is just an index, we don't need that, so I just normally use an underscore to show that it's not in use. The second argument is the element that is currently iterated over, as a plain JS DOM node, and `el` would be exactly the same as `this` in this context.